# Installing boot manager to a raw LVM physical volume

Tags: linux, storage, lvm, partition, boot

Is it possible to install some boot manager to disk with raw physical volume inside (i.e. no partition table)? I tried LILO and LVM volumes became inaccessible (due to LVM structures corruption). Boot mode is BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem, that the bootloaders are a little bit complex today, and practically they need to be booted as well. Even this "bootloader booting code" is too big for the around 300 byte of code in the MBR (master boot record).

This is because the boot loaders are using normally an extra data area, around 10-30 kbyte, *after the master boot record*.

On most default configuration, the data begins only at the first track of the hard drive, which are essentially numbered from 0. On the cylinder 0 so we have around a free track of data, which is freely usable to the boot loaders. On nearly all of the cases I've found it was 63*512=32256 bytes.

It is even so with todays hard disk, which don't show their physical sector layout, only an emulated one (which contains normally 16 or 255 heads, and 63 sector per track).

---

So, this is the case for MBR partitioned disks. If you use LVM, there is no partiton table. There are a lot of opinions in the world of the professional system administration saying "every disk should have a partiton table", or "you simply can't use a disk without partitions", or such. My opinion differs a lot from them: we must admit, the MBR partition is an antediluvian thing and in the era of the logical volume control it is obsolete, and it should be eliminated if it is possible. I think, you had probably a similar consideration to not have an MBR partiton table only a pure LVM layout on your disk.

---

So, but there is a problem with the LVM, and this is that its initial layout doesn't contain this 10-30 kbyte of free data to your boot loader. Next to that, this a little bit uncommon configuration even for the bootload developers. But anyways, it can be done.

In your place I suggest to use LILO. Lilo reads its second-stage boot loader, your kernel and even your initrd from a sector-list, and thus it doesn't need to do any complexer as reading sectors from your hard disks.

If it gives to you some warnings or error messages, please extend your question with your new problem, or even open a new question.